# How to configure RoundCubeMail so I can log in

Tags: macos, webmail, roundcube, icloud-api

I am trying to set up roundcubemail on a **mac** so that I can eventually add an email-pipe to service certain emails.  I have followed the installation and configuration options the best I can, and the tests show no problems except with the test send an email and the iMap test.  The instructions are not very clear about how to set up parts of the config.inc.php.  Here is my config.inc.php:

```
<?php

/* Local configuration for Roundcube Webmail */

// ----------------------------------
// SQL DATABASE
// ----------------------------------
// Database connection string (DSN) for read+write operations
// Format (compatible with PEAR MDB2): db_provider://user:password@host/database
// Currently supported db_providers: mysql, pgsql, sqlite, mssql, sqlsrv, oracle
// For examples see http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.mdb2.intro-dsn.php
// Note: for SQLite use absolute path (Linux): 'sqlite:////full/path/to/sqlite.db?mode=0646'
//       or (Windows): 'sqlite:///C:/full/path/to/sqlite.db'
// Note: Various drivers support various additional arguments for connection,
//       for Mysql: key, cipher, cert, capath, ca, verify_server_cert,
//       for Postgres: application_name, sslmode, sslcert, sslkey, sslrootcert, sslcrl, sslcompression, service.
//       e.g. 'mysql://roundcube:@localhost/roundcubemail?verify_server_cert=false'
$config['db_dsnw'] = 'mysql://roundcubemail:roundcubemail_db_password@localhost/roundcubemail';

// Syslog ident string to use, if using the 'syslog' log driver.
$config['syslog_id'] = 'webmail';

// ----------------------------------
// IMAP
// ----------------------------------
// The IMAP host chosen to perform the log-in.
// Leave blank to show a textbox at login, give a list of hosts
// to display a pulldown menu or set one host as string.
// Enter hostname with prefix ssl:// to use Implicit TLS, or use
// prefix tls:// to use STARTTLS.
// Supported replacement variables:
// %n - hostname ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
// %t - hostname without the first part
// %d - domain (http hostname $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] without the first part)
// %s - domain name after the '@' from e-mail address provided at login screen
// For example %n = mail.domain.tld, %t = domain.tld
// WARNING: After hostname change update of mail_host column in users table is
//          required to match old user data records with the new host.
$config['default_host'] = 'localhost';
//$config['default_host'] = 'ssh://%n';

$config['imap_conn_options'] = array(
  'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verfify_peer_name' => false,
  ),
);
$config['smtp_conn_options'] = array(
  'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
  ),
);
// provide an URL where a user can get support for this Roundcube installation
// PLEASE DO NOT LINK TO THE ROUNDCUBE.NET WEBSITE HERE!
$config['support_url'] = 'mailto://support_email';

// This key is used for encrypting purposes, like storing of imap password
// in the session. For historical reasons it's called DES_key, but it's used
// with any configured cipher_method (see below).
$config['des_key'] = 'aKey';

// Name your service. This is displayed on the login screen and in the window title
$config['product_name'] = 'Webmail';

// ----------------------------------
// PLUGINS
// ----------------------------------
// List of active plugins (in plugins/ directory)
$config['plugins'] = array('archive', 'attachment_reminder', 'emoticons', 'markasjunk', 'new_user_dialog', 'userinfo', 'vcard_attachments');

// the default locale setting (leave empty for auto-detection)
// RFC1766 formatted language name like en_US, de_DE, de_CH, fr_FR, pt_BR
$config['language'] = 'en_US';
```

The iMap and ssl portions are what is confusing to me.  I would like to use the email server on localhost to send emails.  The problem is that after I get it installed, when I access http://localhost/webmail, a login form shows up.  I don't know what to enter for userid or password as I've never specified them when doing the configuration.  I selected auto add new users, but nothing happens.

This is the log entry:

```
    [18-May-2020 19:29:54 -0400]: <d2s7trm8> 
IMAP Error: Login failed for userid against localhost from 127.0.0.1(X-Forwarded-For: ::1).
 Authentication failed. in /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/webmail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php
 on line 200 (POST /webmail/?_task=login&_action=login)
```

What steps do I take to get the iMap and ssl ( if I need it ) to work?

Comment: Th install ssl please follow the instructions here : https://certbot.eff.org/instructions

Comment: also take a look here : https://serverfault.com/questions/915342/getting-roundcube-to-work-with-dovecot-postfix-and-letsencrypt

Comment: I looked at this, but it deals with Dovecote and the suggestions about tls and ssl and the certificate settings are not explained.  I think my problem is understanding the settings I should put here.  My server is a Mac and it uses iCloud mail.  Why does the web mailer not just use that?

Comment: sorry I can not help you with a "mac" or "icloud-mail". I suspect mac is the abbreviation for a computer with the "macos" operating system , so I tagged you question with macos and icloud and lets hope Sculley reads this and helps you with your problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found my error. Ignorance on my part. I was able to log into my round cube webmail on my own server by logging in using my account username and password. I had set the IMAP server to be local host but kept thinking I was supposed to use my local (Apple) email address or such.

When reading installations, it is important to understand that the writer knows things you don’t and doesn’t always explain in detail things that are obvious to them. Reading on the side things about how IMAP servers actually work helped out here to clarify what some of the terms were talking about.

Nice interface once you get logged in!